# Implementing a multithreading function for running "foreach, map and reduce" parallel

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, runnable, scala-3

I am quite new to Scala but I am learning about Threads and Multithreading.

As the title says, I am trying to implement a way to divide the problem onto different threads of variable count.

We are given this code:

```
/** Executes the provided function for each entry in the input sequence in parallel.
 *
 *  @param input the input sequence
 *  @param parallelism the number of threads to use
 *  @param f the function to run
 */
def parallelForeach[A](input: IndexedSeq[A], parallelism: Int, f: A => Unit): Unit = ???
```

I tried implementing it like this:

```
def parallelForeach[A](input: IndexedSeq[A], parallelism: Int, f: A => Unit): Unit = {
  if (parallelism < 1) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("a degree of parallelism < 1 s not allowed for parallel foreach")
  }

  val threads = (0 until parallelism).map { threadId =>
    val startIndex = threadId * input.size / parallelism
    val endIndex = (threadId + 1) * input.size / parallelism
    val task: Runnable = () => {
      (startIndex until endIndex).foreach { A =>
        val key = input.grouped(input.size / parallelism)
        val x: Unit = input.foreach(A => f(A))
        x
      }
    }
    new Thread(task)
  }
  threads.foreach(_.start())
  threads.foreach(_.join())

}
```

for this test:

```
test("parallel foreach should perform the given function once for each element in the sequence") {
        val counter = AtomicLong(0L)
        parallelForeach((1 to 100), 16, counter.addAndGet(_))
        assert(counter.get() == 5050)
```

But, as you can guess, it doesn't work this way as my result isn't 5050 but 505000.

Now here is my question. How do I implement a way to use multithreading efficiently, so there are for example 16 different threads working at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Check your test: "1 to 100".
With your Code you go with each thread through 100, this is why your result is 100 times to large.